# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: .net

My app uses [`File.OpenRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.IO.File.OpenRead%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1%29%3Bk%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) to read a csv file.

This works fine except when the csv file is also open in Excel in which case I get an error

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\test.csv' because it is being used by another process.

What's going on? It makes sense for Excel to block other apps from writing to the file (to prevent conflicts), but why does it stop other apps reading it? Is there any way I can get round it?

Comment: There is no real question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this doesnt answer *why?*, but solves the problem of *how*. There is another way of reading locked files, like this (the key thing is `FileShare.ReadWrite`):

http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2009/04/21/How-do-I-open-a-file-that-is-in-use-in-C

```
 using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(
        "logs/myapp.log",
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            this.textBoxLogs.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```